# Maintain Shiny Session when page reload

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app I used `onSessionEnded` to stop the app, It works when I reload a page, I don't want to expire the session when I reload the tab, I want to maintain the same session. For My application it should end the session when I close the tab. Is this possible in Shiny?

For Example below code works even reloading the page, But I don't want to stop my app when the page refreshed. It should stop the app only when I close the tab.

```
library(shiny)

ui =(
  fluidPage(
    titlePanel("This is an example")
  )
)

server = function(input, output, session){
  session$onSessionEnded({
    print("Stop!")
    stopApp   
  }) 
}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Please help me to solve this problem...

Comment: Shiny has concept of bookmarks, I think this is what you want
https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/bookmarking-state.html

Comment: @PorkChop - Thanks for the quick response, I'm new to shiny, Ill go through the link you proposed :)